# HOW : relative pronoun or relative adverb?

Tags: relative-clauses, relative-pronouns, subordinate-clauses, relative-adverbs

> Relative pronoun : who, whom, whose, which, that
>
> Relative adverb : when, where, why

Is **"how"** *neither a relative pronoun nor an relative adverb?* Then, which category does 'how' belong to?

Comment: I don't believe I've ever seen "how" used in a relative clause. I don't quite know _how_ that would work (sorry for the pun!). I don't see any antecedent to which "_how_" could possibly refer, so it can't be a relative pronoun. I would say that it doesn't have a (relative) category, but I'm sure others are more qualified to answer that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"How" is a flat adverb (an adverb that has no -*ly* ending), and "how" is also an interrogative adverb (an adverb that is used to ask a direct question or an indirect question).{**How** are you doing?} Interrogative adverbs can also "modify some word or phrase in the sentence" in which they appear and "they often present a question about manner" {**How** did the accident happen?} (Garner, 2016, p.131). Additionally, "How" is a **conjunctive adverb** (an adverb that is used to connect a dependent clause to an independent clause), and conjunctive adverbs can introduce noun clauses {I don't understand **how** you arrived at that conclusion.} (Garner, 2016, p.133). Garner indicates 'how' is a conjunctive adverb that can introduce noun clauses; he does not give an example of 'how' connecting a dependent clause to an independent clause.

"How" is not a relative adverb because relative adverbs join "a dependent (subordinate) clause to an independent (main) clause *while modifying the clause of which it is a part*," and relative adverbs, as you know, introduce adjectival clauses and they introduce relative clauses. (Garner, 2016, p.132, *italics mine*). "How" does not introduce adjectival clauses or relative clauses. Adjectival clauses are introduced by a relative pronoun and relative clauses are also introduced by a relative pronoun. See this [link](https://www.ef.com/ca/english-resources/english-grammar/relative-adverbs/) for examples of relative adverbs (with examples of relative adverbs used in sentences).

"How" is also not a relative pronoun. "The most common relative pronouns are *who*, *whom*, *whose*, *which*, and *that*. Sometimes *when* and *where* can be used as relative pronouns as well" ([Relative Pronoun](https://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/pronouns/relative-pronoun.html), n.d.).

In summary:

1. 'How' is a flat adverb
2. 'How' is also an interrogative adverb and
3. 'How' is a conjunctive adverb
4. 'How' is **not** a relative pronoun and
5. 'How' is **not** a relative adverb

I hope this information was helpful.

Comment: I'm wondering how to parse a paraphrase of your example: “How you arrived at that conclusion is beyond me.” What is the subject of this sentence: “how”? Then the subordinate “you arrived at that conclusion“ can stand alone, but the main clause can't: *“How is beyond me.” It's not conjunctive, b/c “is beyond me“ isn't a clause, and not relative. It's more plausible to treat the whole subtree “how you arrived at that conclusion” as the subject here. If it requests a clarification, it may be “I arrived at it /by assuming…”, or even syntactically correct nonsense “…/quickly.” Syntax is damn hard…